# Yii2 post method in not allowed

Tags: post, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I tried to post from frontend in yii2 using postman but i get this

```
{
  "name": "Method Not Allowed",
  "message": "Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: GET, HEAD.",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 405,
  "type": "yii\\web\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException"
}
```

i don't know how to post from the frontend.

this is my front end controller code

```
class TestController extends ActiveController {
    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Test';

    public function behaviors(){
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page', 'X-Pagination-Page-Count'],
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }

    public function actions(){
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['index']);
        return $actions;
    }

    public function actionIndex(){
        $activeData = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Test::find()->orderBy('test_id DESC'),
            'pagination' => [
                'defaultPageSize' => 5,
            ]
        ]);
        return $activeData;
    }

}
```

i am pretty new to programming and need a really simple explanation and example on how to allow post method.

http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=test

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like you inherit your controller from `\yii\rest\ActiveController`. It has `verbs()` method which you have to override in your controller to provide it with proper methods. Here's the `verbs()` from original class:

```
protected function verbs()
{
    return [
        'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
        'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
        'create' => ['POST'],
        'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH'],
        'delete' => ['DELETE'],
    ];
}
```

Try write something like this in your TestController:

```
protected function verbs() {
   $verbs = parent::verbs();
   $verbs['index'] => ['POST']; //methods you need in action
   //or
   $verbs['index'][] => 'POST'; //just add the 'POST' to "GET" and "HEAD"
   return $verbs;
}
```